# Xcode 8 automatic NSManagedObject sublass codegen vs transient properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, xcode8

Since Xcode 8 provides a seemingly great possibility to skip the generation of the NSManagedObject subclasses code and does it itself I wanted to use it in my app. However, I also wanted to use some transient properties for the sake of grouping the objects while using the NSFetchedResultsController. Is this possible to somehow achieve or do I have to traditionally generate the classes and write these properties' implementation by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible without generating the `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

This is likely what the `"Category/Extension"` codegen option helps to address. This codegen option is useful for creating properties (attributes) that you do want Core Data to manage.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to subclass it, try mark your property as transient 
[image]

Then you will be automatically able to access this property.

```
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let newEvent = Event(context: context)

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    newEvent.timestamp = NSDate()
    newEvent.someT = "ABC"
```